# How to know particular port status in osx

Tags: macos, netstat

How can I find particular port status in osx?

I think with `netstat`, I can do it.
But even I read `man netstat`. I could not understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you would like to know which ports are open or filtered, I would suggest getting nmap. It is a linux utility that enables you to virtually scan any IP and obtain information regarding the ports.

You can download the utility here:

http://nmap.org/book/inst-macosx.html